# "Composite type" in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I recall seeing a feature in TypeScript where a type could be composed of another type's properties as well as it's own. But I'm not sure if I'm remembering it correctly. Consider the following:

```
// type or interface
type X = {
  a: number
};

// type or interface
// composes properties from X ???
type XPlus = {
  [P: keyof X], // include properties from X
  b: boolean    // add a new property
};

// instance includes properties from both X and XPlus
const instance: XPlus = {
  a: 100,
  b: false
};
```

This seems to work, but I'm not sure it's doing what I think it is. Does such a feature exist, and if so, what's it called?

Comment: A little unclear since there are a few ways I can see to do this. You may be looking for [extending interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#extending-interfaces), or maybe [intersection types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types)?

Comment: Yes, I was looking for "intersection types". Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just use an intersection type

```
// type or interface
type X = {
    a: number
};


type XPlus = X & {
    b: boolean    // add a new property
};

// instance includes properties from both X and XPlus
const instance: XPlus = {
    a: 100,
    b: false
};
```

Comment: Thanks, just found that! Typescript did not complain when I used the code in my OP, is that also valid?

Comment: `[ P in keyof X]: X[P]` is mapped type syntax, but that doesn't allow you to add extra properties, I was not able to get your code to complie...